# Блочная сортировка двумерного массива из файла

Tags: c++, сортировка

Помогите с кодом.
Мои наработки:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std; 
void bucketSort(vector<float> &x, int n)
{
// 1) Create n empty buckets
vector<float> b[n];

// 2) Put aay elements in different buckets
for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
{
    int bi = n * x[i]; // Index in bucket
    b[bi].push_back(x[i]);
}

// 3) Sort individual buckets
for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    sort(b[i].begin(), b[i].end());

// 4) Concatenate all buckets into x[]
int index = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < b[i].size(); j++)
        x[index++] = b[i][j];
}
int main() {
 ifstream input("input.txt");

    int n(0);
input >> n;
vector<vector<float>> matrix(n, vector<float>(n));
for (int i(0); i < n; ++i) {
    for (int j(0); j < n; ++j)
        input >> matrix[i][j];
}
input.close();
for (int i(0); i < n; ++i)
    bucketSort(matrix[i]);
ofstream output("output.txt");
for (int i(0); i < n; ++i) {
    for (int j(0); j < n; ++j)
        output << matrix[i][j] << ' ';
    output << '\n';
}
output.close();
}'
```

Comment: что делать с кодом?

Comment: Помочь исправить ошибки. Без сортировки он выводит массив в однустроку и бесконечное число нулей. А с сортировкой вообще не работает

Comment: вот так и нужно оформлять свой вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Первым делом нужно исправлять одну грубую ошибку:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < b[i].size(); j++)
            x[index++] = b[i][j];
    }
```

ваш вектор `b` обьявлен с размером равным `n`, и  содержит элементы типа `float`, а не вектор.  `b[i][j]` не может быть правильным, а `b[n - 1][b[i].size() - 1]` тем более...